# select a className that is in div className CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi i have two different html divs that contain the same price class ="uvp uvp-price".

```
 <div class="product-detail-price-container">
    <meta itemprop="price" content="119.8">                                                             
    <p class="uvp uvp-price">UVP: 50,00&nbsp;€</p>
    <p class="twp-product-detail-price" style="margin-top: -52px;">EK: 29.95 €</p>
 </div>
```

and

```
<div class="product-price-info">
    <div class="tw-price-unit"></div>
    <p class="uvp uvp-price">UVP: 50,00&nbsp;€</p>
 </div>
```

now i only want to give the first **uvp uvp-price** class that is inside the div class **product-detail-price-container** a padding-top: 15px;

i tried this but doesnt work.

```
.product-detail-price-container:has(.uvp-price) {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

what am i doing wrong ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`>` selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) to get a class inside something:

```css
.product-detail-price-container > .uvp.uvp-price
```

```css
.product-detail-price-container > .uvp.uvp-price {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-detail-price-container">
    <meta itemprop="price" content="119.8">                                                             
    <p class="uvp uvp-price">UVP: 50,00&nbsp;€</p>
    <p class="twp-product-detail-price" style="margin-top: -52px;">EK: 29.95 €</p>
 </div>


<div class="product-price-info">
    <div class="tw-price-unit"></div>
    <p class="uvp uvp-price">UVP: 50,00&nbsp;€</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css direct child selector to do this easily. Just replace your class from `.product-detail-price-container:has(.uvp-price)` to `.product-detail-price-container > .uvp.uvp-price`

Final css:

```
.product-detail-price-container > .uvp.uvp-price {padding-top: 15px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :first-child for select the first child of parent
so:

```
.product-detail-price-container .uvp.uvp-price:first-child {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

and you can also use :nth-child(1) for this :

```
.product-detail-price-container .uvp.uvp-price:nth-child(1) {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Please do not forget to mention the limitations: https://caniuse.com/?search=first-child and https://caniuse.com/?search=nth-child